# Convert date/time format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, time, date, format

My shapefile contains a attribute field called "created" (type QString) and this field holds the date and time of every feature in this format: "2022-03-04-13-28-26" (yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss)

I want to create a new attribute field that automatically converts this format into the following format: "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm" (consider space between date and time and leave away the seconds)

How to do that?

I am using QGIS 3.16.6

Comment: Have you checked with the documentation, especially the [`format_date`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=format_date#format-date)-page? If so, what is unclear to you?

Comment: Shapefiles, based on the dBase-Iii+ (-ish) format of the '80s, do not support a date type at higher than day resolution (amazingly, they were not subject to Y2K issues). Reformatting a string to new string is a trivial exercise in Python, requiring only `str.split()` and `str.format()`. Also the definition of "automatically" is unclear. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @Kazuhito's answer works perfectly, I just wanted to add an alternative solution using `to_datetime` to make a datetime object and `format_date` to convert it back to a formatted string:

```
format_date(
    to_datetime(original_datetime_string, 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss'),  -- make datetime of input string
    'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'                                             -- format the datetime object back to a string with elements rearranged
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is far better than my answer, neat and clear!

Comment: thanks matt! very useful to me.

Answer (score 6):

A Field Calculator expression tested in QGIS 3.16.16

```
array_to_string(array_reverse(string_to_array(left("created", 10), '-')),'.')+' '+substr("created", 12, 2)+':'+substr("created", 15, 2)
```

[image]

which works like below:

```
array_to_string(                            // This will change the array to string
     array_reverse(                         // Re-orders [2022,03,04] to [04,03,2022]
         string_to_array(                   // Changes "created" to an array
             left("created", 10), '-')),'.' // Takes the first 10 chars
              )+' '+                        // Inserts a space
substr("created", 12, 2)+':'+               // Extracts hh and adds ':'
substr("created", 15, 2)                    // Extracts mm
```

Comment: Kazuhito: Thank you very much for giving a simple solution (and explanation) without being arrogant or making me feel like a silly person. I am no GIS expert and don't want to become one at all but I unfortunately have some tasks to do in GIS for which I need help from kind persons like you! All the best for you and kindest regards... Hannes

Comment: Hannes, Thanks so much, but please see the other answer provided by Matt. I think you should follow that one.